# The Apache mod rewrite module doesn't work when using the IP

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, drupal

I've got a Drupal setup locally. When I access the homepage using my IP everything works. When I try any "re-written" url (such as 10.0.150.4/user) I get a not found.

When I replace my IP with an alias (and put that in my hosts) all urls work.

Here's my 000-default:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/g/www/paddle
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/g/www/paddle>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable the 000-default site apparently.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and you haven't realy learned anything... I think your problem is that you thought you had a virtual host, but didn't. Your 000-default file doesn't contain a ServerName directive for example. So everything was probably served from the main context. What is the output of apache2ctl -S?

Comment: but I actually got what I wanted: locally I can still use a serveralias to access my website, and externally people from the LAN can use my IP.

Comment: @KristvanBesien: A `<VirtualHost>` need not contain a ServerName directive.  In the absence of one, it will use the top-level ServerName (typically dynamically determined).  Additionally, any configured and applicable (based on its IP/port tuple(s)) VHost will always "win" versus the main context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running Drupal from a subdirectory of your website (ie, `http://127.0.0.1/` is not a Drupal site, but `http://127.0.0.1/asdf` is the "root" of the Drupal site). If that's the case you need to open the `.htaccess` file, you'll find a line that starts `RewriteBase`, which needs to know what the "root" path to Drupal should be.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work is that you are setting `AllowOverride none` in your 000-default VHost.  This means that the clean URL feature in Drupal won't work, since it's reliant on a `.htaccess` file.  Simply change that line to `AllowOverride all` and everything will work like a champ.